# How to share my cart via mail with others magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, email

I want to add the possibility of sharing a cart with others via mail so  is their a solution for that please  because i did not find any article that can help me in this

Comment: Check this share cart extension which gives you the option to share cart via email - https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-share-cart-save-cart.html

Comment: thanks for your replay can you please help me in this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274883/how-to-load-collection-by-product-for-custom-attribute-product-type-dropdown-mag